# how to get android element's 'resource id' and 'content description' attributes value in appium java?

Tags: java, android, appium, android-uiautomator

I wanted to get resource id and content description of android elements at runtime.

i tried this:

```
myElement.getAttribute("resource-id")
myElement.getAttribute("content-desc")
```

but getting error as "`this element does not have the resource-id attribute`".

Is there any way to  get this ?

Answer (score 9):

According to this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/appium-discuss/iYT294swjew/kPD0RIr6myEJ), the way to get "content-desc" is to use 
myElement.getAttribute("name").

Answer (score 7):

for resource-id use: `webElement.getAttribute("resourceId")`

Comment: This one worked with me when using AdnroidDriver to resource-id attribute for AndroidElement

Answer (score 1):

To get content-desc use:

`myElement.getAttribute("contentDescription")`